# Core Bluetooth with Bluetooth 2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Can I connect iPhone and bluetooth 2.1 device and work with them via Core Bluetooth? I just need to send and receive some NSString data from/to iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Core Bluetooth only supports Bluetooth Low Energy/Bluetooth 4.0 devices. You can only connect to Bluetooth 2.1 devices via the MFI program and the external accessory framework.

The only exception is "standard" devices such as keyboards and audio devices (hands free etc). However in these cases you can't access any underlying Bluetooth information - you can simply send audio or receive keyboard input.

Comment: Mice don't work with non-jailbroken iOS devices, and if you jailbreak you can use any profiles with BTStack.

Answer (score 0):

The only way your own device talk to your iPhone is Bluetooth Low energy if you can not apply MFI program(Most of cases). You need some Bluetooth Low Energy DevKit like TI2540/TI2541 or Nordic or Dialog, they are equipped with rich interface like UART, button, LED and simple speaker. The cheapest chip on market is TI2540(also oldest), but it is MCS51 based core MCU, not very friendly. Other arm based dev kits are more friendly.
The core bluetooth in iOS is not very easy to use, I will recommend you try https://github.com/kickingvegas/YmsCoreBluetooth , it is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to work with 2.1 bluetooth in core bluetooth library.
Core bluetooth support Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) support.Ex. Bluetooth 4 or greater version of BLE devices.
Bluetooth 2.1 is classic bluetooth device.